# How to install Google Play store to my Android 13.0 desktop version

Tags: android-studio, installation, android-emulator, google-play-services

I want to run Android Studio like emulator because I like the desktop version of Android. But there is no Play Store and I am not able to install is manually.

I download the Google Play Store apk file, but it does not work.

After watching a YouTube video, I try to edit the config file

```
"C:\Users\omarf\.android\avd\Medium_Desktop_API_33.avd\config.ini")
```

to this..

```
PlayStore.enabled=true 

image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
```

It Works but Changed to Tab Mode. I do not able to multitask with lots of windows like Desktop. At One time it shows me One Windows like Smartphone.